# how skip some specific files in multiple subfolders in matlab?

Tags: matlab, file, dirname

I need to skip some specific files in different sub-folders. So I tried by line "if filename"  in the snippet that if the filename not contains raw, info, do some operations, but it doesn't work. I really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction how can I skip these filenames which does have specific character like "raw" or "info."..

```
input_dirName = dir('D:\Neda\Pytorch\CAMUS\training\');
Output_dirName = 'D:\Neda\Pytorch\CAMUS\data\';
GT_dirName =  'D:\Neda\Pytorch\CAMUS\GT\';

dirName = 'D:\Neda\Pytorch\CAMUS\training\';
fileList = SureScan_getAllFiles(dirName);


foldername = fullfile({input_dirName.folder}, {input_dirName.name});
foldername = foldername(3:end);


for k = 1:length(fileList)-50

filename = fileList{k};

if filename ~= contains(filename,'raw') | filename ~= contains(filename,'Info_') | filename ~= contains(filename,'sequence.mhd')| filename ~=contains(filename,'_sequence')    

% do some operation
end
end
```

Comment: @SardarUsama I couldn't understand what you mean. Could you please provide a simple example.

Comment: @Sardar Usama thank you for the clarification. so, what do you recommend if I want to skip some of files in multiple folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `contains` is either `true` or `false` and hence it will never be equal to any filename.

To skip filenames that have any of `'raw'`, `'Info_'`, `'sequence.mhd'` or `'_sequence'`, use:

```
if ~contains(filename, {'raw', 'Info_', 'sequence.mhd', '_sequence'})    
   %do some operation
end
```